# Fill new array from string that contains many parameters

Tags: javascript

I tried to write this code, and I got issues regarding how to make it.

1. I have got this string

```
"_id": "a9529fcf-f822-454e-8070-0157b3bbf0cf",
"_rev": "3",
"sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ]
```

2. Fill array string with the string taken as input
3. Analise string to retrive `[ "21 34 49234328 9" ]`. I know there are blank spaces and i need to jump charter like [ , ] , "
4. Get numeric values that are as string  and fill them in a array

Can anyone help me find the solution? Or just any help? Thanks in advance.

```js
//  insert string to process
var test = '_id": "a9529fcf-f822-454e-8070-0157b3bbf0cf", "_rev": "3", "sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ] ';
var arraybuild = [''];
var string_to_process = prompt("Please provvide string :", test);
if (string_to_process != "") {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = string_to_process + "\n";
  // insert string inside array string
  for (var i = 0; i < string_to_process.length; i++) {
    arraybuild.push(string_to_process[i]);
    console.log(arraybuild[string_to_process[i - 1]]);
  }
  // values are stored inside array
  if (arraybuild != null) {
    for (var j = 0; j = arraybuild.lenght; j++) {
      document.getElementById('display').InnerHTML = "value[" + j + "] :  " + arraybuild[j - 1];
    }
    // check  for  charters like [ ]
    var newarray = [''];
    for (var z = 0; z < arraybuild.length; z++) {
      if (arraybuild != null) {
        // CHECK DELLA SINTASSI PER LE STRINGHE
        // ENTRA SOLO UNA VOLTA
        if (arraybuild[z] == '[') {
          // switch
          var index = arraybuild[z].index;
          z = index;
          console.log("index jumped to value  : " + z);
          if (/\s/.test(arraybuild[z]) || arraybuild[z] == '  "  ') {
            console.log("trovato carattere non valido :" + arraybuild.indexOf(z));
          } else {
            if (isNumeric(arraybuild[z])) {
              console.log("inserimento dei caratteri all'interno dell'array : " + arraybuild[z]);
              document.getElementById('after_index').innerHTML += "values :  " + arraybuild[z] + " ";
              //  SEPARATORE COME UNA VIRGOLA TRA NUMERI
              newarray.push(arraybuild[z]);
              if (arraybuild[z].indexOf(']')) {
                break;
              }
            }

            // TO BE CONTINUED
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<p style = ' border : 1px solid red '>Valore non trovato [  \n </p>";
        }

      } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<p style = ' border : 1px solid red '>L'array e' null</p>";
      }
    }
  } else {
    //arraybuild.lenght = 0;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "<p style = ' border : 1px solid red '>Array is Empty</p>";
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<p style = ' border : 1px solid red '>Nessuna stringa da processare trovata</p>";
}

// get values between range [ maybe some split of it  ]

// create temp array that should be the prospect of .cvs file

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Your "string" looks like json - is it a json string?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this of JSON format? Convert it to an object.

convert to object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "_id": "a9529fcf-f822-454e-8070-0157b3bbf0cf","_rev": "3","sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ]}');

Get the property you need:
var stringToAnalize =obj.sIDHistory[0]
```

loop through the string and check for space like you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the provided input format, there is a nice trick

```
  let test = '"_id": "a9529fcf-f822-454e-8070-0157b3bbf0cf", "_rev": "3", "sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ] ';
  test = '{' + test + '}'
  test = JSON.parse(test);
  test.sIDHistory = test.sIDHistory[0].split(' ').map(e => +e);
  console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a json object, you can parse it with `JSON.parse` and then split the `sIDHistory` to get your numbers, e.g.:

```js
var test = '{"_id": "a9529fcf-f822-454e-8070-0157b3bbf0cf", "_rev": "3", "sIDHistory": [ "21 34 49234328 9" ]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(test);
var historyIdStr = obj.sIDHistory[0];
var historyIds = historyIdStr.split(/\s+/).map(Number);

console.log(historyIds);
```